# Log long variables in Titanium Studio

Tags: logging, titanium

maybe I'll need to reformulate the question..

I'm trying to find the complete value of some variable in my Titanium project but I can't find a way to do so.

For now, I tried to "Watch" the variable in Titanium Studio, but have an incomplete value like

```
<web:myFunc soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/en... (length: 37435)
```

So I looked over the [Titanium.API](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.API-method-debug) submodule, with Ti.API.Info(myVariable), but these methods only print up to 4096 bytes of data... As you can see, it's quite far from the actual length

Does someone have an idea to get the full value of this kind of variable? If it can help, my project is planned for Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for the one facing the same problem, my solution was to write it inside a file on the device sdcard.

Here is how it's done:

```
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.getExternalStorageDirectory(),'test.txt');
f.write(myVar);
```

On iOS, there is this method:

```
f.createFile();
```

But I don't know if it is necessary, maybe someone with the answer could edit this part.

Then, you have to use DDMS to retrieve the file, there is a perspective for that in Titanium Studio and Eclipse. But if you don't find it, you can go to the android sdk installation folder :

> sdk/tools/ddms.bat

EDIT: ddms seems to be deprecated, instead, use :

> sdk/tools/monitor.bat

You can explore the emulator's files from those two.

It launches the app, then, if you have your emulator running, it will allow you to look at the files in your explorer. Then, you juste have to use the 'pull' to save the file on your computer.
If you want to know the actual path of your file, you can use :

```
Ti.API.info(f.getNativePath());
```

Hope it'll save some time to the next one facing this issue...